# What’s a matter-of-fact tone?

Tags: slang, formality, writing, present-tense, tone

I was wondering if a matter-of-fact tone was the same as a straightforward tone, and if these terms all mean “simple” or “without emotions”.  (I am not a native speaker for that matter).
If I speak or say something in a “matter-of-fact way” how am I saying it?

Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: There is some description of this in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/matter_of_fact).

Comment: As a newsreader rather than an extremist or fanatical lobbyist would read it out.

Comment: Thank you lots! So if I understand, a matter-of-fact tone is neutral and unemotional? Like someone who tells the news?